# inserting variable in mssql by python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to make a script which is importing data to mssql from Excel.

I read data from Excel and assigned to variables. It works, I'm checking by printing it. Connecting to database and inserting string works correctly, too. But it doesn't insert variables. Please help me to find a solution.

python script:

```
for rownum in range(1,sheet.nrows): 
    if sheet.row_values(rownum)[0]=='':
        pass
    else:
        vals=[sheet.row_values(rownum)]
        val = sheet.cell_value(rownum, 1)
        val2=sheet.cell_value(rownum, 2)
        val3=sheet.cell_value(rownum, 3)
        val1=sheet.cell_value(rownum, 0)
        val4=sheet.cell_value(rownum, 4)
        val5=sheet.cell_value(rownum, 5)
        val1= val1.encode("utf-8")
        val4 = val4.encode("utf-8")
        val5 = val5.encode("utf-8")
        dat=int(val)
        dt=date.fromordinal(date(1990,1,1).toordinal()+dat-2)
        x = int(val2 * 24 * 3600)
        x3 = int(val3 * 24 * 3600)# convert to number of seconds
        m = time(x//3600, (x%3600)//60, x%60)
        m3 = time(x3//3600, (x3%3600)//60, x3%60)
        cursor.executemany ("INSERT INTO [sample.dbo.tv_prot_virt_im](chan_name,pr_date,start_time,end_time,prog_name,pr_genre) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)", [val1,dt,m,m3,val4,val5])
        connection.commit()
```

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/akylyshbekova/Desktop/PyQT/main_test.py", line 26, in <module>
    tab = Table('dbo.tv_prot_virt_im',metadata,autoload=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 439, in __new__
    metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 434, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 514, in _init
    include_columns, _extend_on=_extend_on)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 540, in _autoload
    _extend_on=_extend_on
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2044, in run_callable
    with self.contextual_connect() as conn:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2112, in contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2151, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1465, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 387, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][\xc4\xe8\xf1\xef\xe5\xf2\xf7\xe5\xf0 \xe4\xf0\xe0\xe9\xe2\xe5\xf0\xee\xe2 ODBC] \xc8\xf1\xf2\xee\xf7\xed\xe8\xea \xe4\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xf5 \xed\xe5 \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed \xe8 \xed\xe5 \xf3\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xed \xe4\xf0\xe0\xe9\xe2\xe5\xf0, \xe8\xf1\xef\xee\xeb\xfc\xe7\xf3\xe5\xec\xfb\xe9 \xef\xee \xf3\xec\xee\xeb\xf7\xe0\xed\xe8\xfe (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: That error clearly isn't coming from the code you've posted. The traceback shows it coming from the place where you instantiate `Table`.

Comment: seems like problem in coding. if I print val1,dt,m,m3,val4,val5 it's normal look, when I try write it on list s=[val1,dt,m,m3,val4,val5]
        print s result it is like [u'\u0441\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0440\u043d\u044b\u0439 ', datetime.date(2107, 8, 17), datetime.time(10, 30, 1), datetime.time(11, 0), u'\u041c\u0443\u043b\u044c\u0442\u0444\u0438\u0